# csv mapper to json with different field names

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I would like to convert a csv file to a json file/output. The csv file has headers. I want to map the csv headers to different fields in the json file or output.
So say the csv file contains headers category, currency. I want the json to have field names cat, crcy.

I am using CsvSchema, CsvMapper and a Pojo.

```
CsvSchema csvSchema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();
CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();

MappingIterator<Test> csvLines = csvMapper.readerFor(Test.class)
                .with(csvSchema)
                .readValues(new File("src/main/resources/test.csv"));

ObjectMapper jsonMapper =  new ObjectMapper()
                .configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

csvLines.forEachRemaining(test -> {
            try {
                System.out.println(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(test));
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

This maps the header names to json field names. Can I configure the Test pojo to map to different fields or add the mappings some other way?

One solution/approach is to use a mixin class.
So have a class FromCsv  with json properties category and currency mapped to fields cat and crcy. And a class ToJson  with fields cat and crcy.

```
 CsvSchema csvSchema = csvMapper
                .schemaFor(FromCsv.class)
                .withHeader();
csvMapper.addMixIn(ToJson.class, FromCsv.class);
MappingIterator<ToJson> jsonLines = csvMapper.readerFor(ToJson.class)
                .with(csvSchema)
                .readValues(new File("src/main/resources/test_fcs.csv"));
```

Thanks,
B.

Comment: I was submitting a solution based on the annotation of the getters of your `Test` class. Still interested in it ?

Comment: Yes, I am still interested. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Can I configure the Test pojo to map to different fields or add the
> mappings some other way?

Yes, you can do it annotating its getters with [`JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) like below :

```
public class Test {
    private String category;
    private String currency;

    @JsonProperty("cat") //<-- in the serialization category will be replaced by cat
    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    @JsonProperty("crcy") //<-- in the serialization currency will be replaced by crcy
    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this earlier, but to make this work, I had to also change csv schema to reference pojo -> csvMapper.schemaFor(FromCsv.class).withHeader()

Comment: @user518066 Yes, my solution uses the jsonmapper included in your code, while your solution uses the mixin class erasing the need of an explicite jsonmapper instance.